R gamlss - Last error message: object 'fit' not found
After executing several data correctly, it throws the error : Last error message: object 'fit' not found
any ideas?
train_modelo<-function(data,x){
  codigo <- x[,1]
  family <- x[,2]
  modelo <- gamlss(formula = tx ~ pb(tx1) + pb(hr1) + pb(rsx1) + mes + pb(tx2), 
                   sigma.formula = ~pb(hr1),
                   nu.formula = ~1, 
                   tau.formula = ~1,
                   data = data.frame(data), 
                   family = family,
                   trace = TRUE,
                   control = gamlss.control(n.cyc = 300),
                   method=mixed(70,500))
  print(codigo)
  return(modelo)
}


ERROR:
Last error message:
    object 'fit' not found
Last error traceback:
    entrenar_modelo(train, distribucionXestacion)
    gamlss(formula = tx ~ pb(tx1) + pb(hr1) + pb(rsx1) + mes + pb(tx2),     ...
    eval(substitute(method))
    eval(substitute(method))
    mixed(70, 500)
    RS(n.cyc = n1, no.warn = FALSE)
    glim.fit(f = sigma.object, X = sigma.X, y = y, w = w, fv = sigma,      o...
    .handleSimpleError(function (condition)  {     state$error <- build_mess...
    h(simpleError(msg, call))


It works on one computer and when running it on a new computer it gives the error, try leaving the same package versions but the error persists. Everything is executed through target
